# given 4 values q,w,e and problems, how to solve the given problem

Tags: python, algorithm

I am working on a problem in which you are given three values `q,w,e` `q` is how many problems one can solve in an hour, `w` is how many consecutive hours one can solve problems for, and `e` is how many hours of rest is required between "work" sessions.

I am given `q,w,e` and the number of problems that need to be solved

I have to output the hours (rounded up to the closest integer) it will take for a student to complete the problems.

This is the code I have tried, but it does not work for all possible `q,w,e` values.

```
problems = int(input())
q = int(input())
w = int(input())
e = int(input())
problems_solved = 0
hours = 0
while problems_solved < problems:
    problems_solved+=q
    hours+=1
    if hours % w == 0 and problems_solved < problems:
        hours+=e
print(hours)
```

Comment: The error in the code is that `hours+=e` will throw off the `hours % w` calculation. For example if `w` is 3 and `e` is 2, the student will work for three hours, then rest for 2. At that point `hours` is 5. So the student will work for one hour, and then rest again.

Comment: seems that this can be done in `O(1)`, not in `O(problems/q)`

Comment: interesting @user3386109 can you elaborate, and help fix my solution if possible?

Comment: Can you help me fix my solution @user3365922

Comment: Kindly have a look at the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition `hours % w` is causing the problem here. As in the question, the rest has to be taken after `w` hours or `w` working hours. But, you are simultaneously adding rest hours and working hours into a single variable(`hours`), which is logically incorrect.

**Solution:** Maintain a separate variable to calculate the rest hours as follows:

```
 problems = int(input())
 q = int(input())
 w = int(input())
 e = int(input())
 problems_solved = 0
 work_hours = 0
 rest_hours = 0
 while problems_solved < problems:
     problems_solved+=q
     work_hours+=1
     if work_hours % w == 0 and problems_solved < problems:
          rest_hours+=e
 print(work_hours + rest_hours)
```